# Post-process request event in Pyramid/Pylons

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

Is there an event or some kind of work with middlelayer where the request is already sent to the user, but we still have the information so we can do stuff on the DB later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably already know about, you can do *before* request handing with:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/narr/events.html#configuring-an-event-listener-imperatively

To handle post-request stuff (without using middleware) you need to add a finished callback to the request which is demonstrated here:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.add_finished_callback

Of course that finished callback only occurs within the scope of one request.  You can handle all requests by combining the two:

```
from pyramid.events import NewRequest

def do_something(request):
    # do something here
    pass

def setup_post_request(event):
    event.request.add_finished_callback(do_something)

config.add_subscriber(setup_post_request, NewRequest)
```

Comment: This is what i was loking for, middlelayer not needed, thas

Answer (score 1):

In Pylons, each controller can have a **before** and **after** methods you can define that's then called before/after the controller method called.

There's also the lib/base.py file which contains the controller call and you could add some custom code there, but it will be called on every request and can be dangerous if your code produces some errors.

I'm not sure in Pyramid.

If you do things in a custom middleware, you'll have access to the request and response objects, but not other material. You could in theory parse the .ini config for the db settings and such, but if it's really part of the app, I'd stick to a place there.